# Significant digits when converting JSON using fromJSON in jsonlite

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I am converting JSON to R objects using `fromJSON` from the `jsonlite` package, but numeric values are being rounded.  How can I control the precision for converted numeric values?

**Example**

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON('{"lon": -86.143278324353244}')
## $lon
## [1] -86.14328

## Desired output is -86.143278324353244
```

Looking into the `jsonlite` code, I've traced the function calls back to R_parse, in [parse.c](https://github.com/jeroenooms/jsonlite/blob/master/src/parse.c)

```
.Call(jsonlite:::R_parse, "-86.143278324353244", FALSE)
## [1] -86.14328
```

**Other attempts**

- `fromJSON` has a `digits` argument, but it isn't a valid argument with `toJSON`.
- Other packages like `rjson` and `RJSONIO` yield similar results.

Comment: The values aren't being rounded internally. R just doesn't print all digits by default because that's usually a bit unruly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's there...

```
> print(fromJSON('{"lon": -86.143278324353244}'), digits=20)
$lon
[1] -86.143278324353247
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is still visiting this - I'm hitting something similar, and afaict, it is the limit that JSON only has a float type, and the `fromJSON` import is rounding.
In my case I was trying to read in a nanosecond value, and it gets bumped by 13ns or so. If you run in R:

```
suppressMessages(library(jsonlite))
options(digits=22)
x=fromJSON('{"ns": 1567002188374607769}')
print(x)
print(fromJSON('{"ns": 1567002188374607769}'), digits=22)
```

I see:

```
$ns
[1] 1567002188374607872

$ns
[1] 1567002188374607872
```

`...872` != `...769`  I have not come up with a nice solution, apart from maybe store the ns value as a JSON string instead...

Answer (score 0):

Using the setting `options(digits = 30)` solve the issue in my case.