# nested lists / unnest_wider: losing digits after comma?

Tags: r, json, list, tidyr, unnest

I am downloading a json file which contains coordinates (mercator format) in a list format.
When I open the resulting dataframe/tibble I can see that the coordinates have decimal places (digits after the comma e.g. .4, .58). See the screenshot.

[image]

When I print the list, the decimal places are missing. They are also missing when unnesting the list (tidyr::unnest_wider). Any idea what's going on here? I fail to understand why I don't see the digits after the comma. Many thanks.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'jsonlite'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     flatten

data_link <- "https://www.statistik.at/gs-atlas/ATLAS_SCHULE_WFS/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ATLAS_SCHULE_WFS:ATLAS_SCHULE&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsname=EPSG:3857&"

df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data_link, flatten=TRUE) %>% 
  pluck("features") %>%  #extract nested list with data on schools
  select(id, geometry.coordinates) %>% 
  as_tibble()

class(df$geometry.coordinates)
#> [1] "list"
head(df$geometry.coordinates)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1816122 6131866
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1819987 6131752
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1808519 6129276
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 1810436 6132934
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 1834892 6142691
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 1830091 6147081

df %>% 
  head() %>% 
  mutate(geometry.coordinates=map(geometry.coordinates, set_names, c("long", "lat"))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col = c("geometry.coordinates"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   id                                              long      lat
#>   <chr>                                          <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f69fdc2_2a59 1816122. 6131866.
#> 2 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f69fdc2_2a5a 1819987. 6131752.
#> 3 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f69fdc2_2a5b 1808518. 6129276.
#> 4 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f69fdc2_2a5c 1810436. 6132934.
#> 5 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f69fdc2_2a5d 1834892. 6142691.
#> 6 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f69fdc2_2a5e 1830091. 6147081.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038349/significant-digits-when-converting-json-using-fromjson-in-jsonlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a display issue which could be solved using `options`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

options(digits = 12) #Or any higher number

df$geometry.coordinates[[1]]
#[1] 1816122.40 6131865.58
```

and for display of tibbles, use

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 12) #Or any higher number

df %>% 
  head() %>% 
  mutate(geometry.coordinates=map(geometry.coordinates, set_names, c("long", "lat"))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(col = c("geometry.coordinates"))

#  id                                                 long        lat
#  <chr>                                             <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f7f16a0_-70d8 1816122.4  6131865.58
#2 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f7f16a0_-70d7 1819987.4  6131752.22
#3 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f7f16a0_-70d6 1808518.5  6129276.28
#4 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f7f16a0_-70d5 1810435.84 6132934.36
#5 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f7f16a0_-70d4 1834891.98 6142690.97
#6 ATLAS_SCHULE.fid--3c550d5d_1702f7f16a0_-70d3 1830091.28 6147080.61
```